# Word for "satiating" or "satisfying" hunger and thirst

Tags: word-choice

I have a context in which I need to say that something ***meets*** or ***satisfies*** both hunger and thirst at the same time. The subject is abstract and I need only one verb a bit more formal, or let's say *more sophisticated* than "satisfy" if possible. To be more precise, here is an example:

> Such words ***...*** the hunger and thirst of their souls, you must not stop writing!

Comment: Is 'quench' suitable here?

Comment: Quench can specifically ne used with thirst, but not with hunger. So I am afraid not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regret that the niches of my vocabulary have not rendered up a word that **only** applies to hunger and thirst.

I might use the verb *assuage*.

> *assuage* = to make unpleasant feelings less strong
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assuage)

The word applies to feelings other than only hunger and thirst, as do the other two candidates:

> quell = If you quell an unpleasant feeling such as fear or anger, you stop yourself or other people from having that feeling
>
> [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quell)

> alleviate = to make (something, such as pain or suffering) more bearable
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alleviate)

Of the three I prefer *assuage* for its feeling of actually reducing the feeling rather than *alleviate*'s feeling of merely making the feeling more bearable. Also, "assuage thirst" dominated the others until the early 1900s, after which the three alternatives seem to have been used, with "quell thirst" in a small minority according to:

[Google ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assuage+thirst&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassuage%20thirst%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cassuage%20thirst%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Comment: The last time I heard 'assuage' was in a school study on something Biblical, I think.

Comment: I think _**assuage**_ is simply exquisite in this case, just the word I need. I was thinking of something like _**fill**_, but _**assuage**_ is a million times better. Funny, I only thought of "assuage" in terms of _pain_ ("Assuage their pain"). Thank you, Anton

Comment: Thanks! *Assuage* hunger with an anagrammatic *sausage* perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The word [**quench**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quench) is applied primarily to thirst, and also to (passionate) desires, but the word [**slake**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/slake) can be used to satify (or remove) any desire. Lexico has

> **slake**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1.1** Satisfy (desires)
> *Art is there to slake our continuing appetite for mystery.*

So I suggest

> Such words **slake** the hunger and thirst of their souls, you must not stop writing!

Comment: Slake does not seem to apply very well to [hunger](https://www.alphadictionary.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=5800) though...

Comment: @fev as applied to hunger for food, perhaps, but the usage is more general (as in the dictionary quote for 1.1). The question isn't about eating and drinking.

Comment: oh, ok, I see what you mean. You think it is alright for _abstract hunger_ . Interesting.